# Find minimum overlap between 2 rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

So I have 2 datasets regarding purchasing in bulk yields a different total.  An example would be that:  It's cheaper to buy 200 than it is 180 so it will never make sense to purchase 180, if you buy 180 always buy 200

So I'd like to find where the max value in dataset 2 where it is less than dataset one

Example

```
    **Data set 1**                **Data set 2**                result
                                  (starts at 200)           
    Quantity  Price  Total      Quantity  Price  Total     customer need  best value    
    10        18.48  181                                     10               10
    195       18.48  3603         288     12.48  3594       195             288  
    196       18.48  3622         289     12.48  3606       196             290
    197       18.48  3641         290     12.48  3619       197             291
    198       18.48  3659         291     12.48  3632       198             291              
    199       18.48  3677         292     12.48  3664       199             293              
    200       18.48  3696         293     12.48  3657       200             293
```

What would the best value formula be?  If (C1 > F1:f7, max(F1:f7 where C1 > F1:F7), C1) OR

Here is a graph

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a fully VBA solution or a formula to put in the cells?

Comment: ideally a formula. VBA would be an acceptable answer

Comment: updated to include a visual.  It's like comparing the difference between 2 slopes

Answer (score 1):

[image: MaxSumIf]

**Updated:**

```
=IF(C2>$F$2,MAX(IF($F$2:$F$7<C2,$D$2:$D$7,0)),A2)
```

**Update (if F is not in ascending order):**

```
=IF(SUM(IF(C2>$F$2:$F$7,1,0))>0,MAX(IF($F$2:$F$7<C2,$D$2:$D$7,0)),A2)
```

Comment: There was a small mistake in the first formula. The above answer should be both simpler and correct.

Comment: I think C2 should be compared to the entirety of F2:F7 (F:F) because the 2 lines have different slops.  So in some cases like 198 and 199 they get the same value.  I used the comparison at the break point so it appears close but the further away from that point we get, the difference in values would be greater

Comment: I originally compared C2 to Column F, but isn't F ascending in value?

Comment: My revision compares C2 to the entirety of F

Comment: if you want to take my answer and copy it to your's I can mark it as correct.  I really appreciate your effort

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a combination of Vlookup and Index/Match.  Vlookup found the next closest price, index/match was used to get the quantity.

```
INDEX(D$1:D$7, MATCH(VLOOKUP(C1,F$3:F$401,1,TRUE), F$3:F$401,0))
```

get the value of how many 2 buy from dataset 2 if value is lower.  If there was no price found then I got NA so I used an if NA to get the result

```
=IFNA(INDEX(D$1:D$7, MATCH(VLOOKUP(C1,F$3:F$401,1,TRUE), F$3:F$401,0)), A1)
```